# Do Swift Playgrounds created on iOS work in macOS version?

Tags: swift-playground

I created a playground on my iPad, then transferred it to my macOS.

When I try to launch it in the macOS version I get:

[image: macOS playground error]

Comment: What happened after you applied the update?

Comment: See answer... basically it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to `Version 3.4.1 (1302.34)`

The Playground appears differently, below the name, it shows "Swift 5.3" and the playground does work on macOS now.